# How can I install Eclipse Indigo on Windows 7

Tags: python, eclipse, windows-7, python-3.x

I've downloaded Eclipse Indigo in preparation of using it to write apps in Python. There doesn’t seem to be an install file. When I double-clicked `eclipse.exe` the program just ran. Can I move the Eclipse directory anywhere I want it, create a shortcut and place it on my taskbar, and start writing programs?

I put the Eclipse directory in my Path statement, and tried to run it from the command line. It won’t run anywhere but in the Eclipse directory. I already have Python 3.2 installed and it *does* run anywhere from the command line. Will Eclipse automatically find my Python executable or do I have to do something else?

Comment: there's no install, eclipse starts directely bu running eclipse.exe.

Comment: Thanks! I found instructions to install the pydev plugin and installed the plugin. Now I need instructions on writing a python script in Eclipse. Any links that would be appropriate for a beginner? The only experience I've had with programming is with visual products like Delhi/lazarus and MS Visual C++

Comment: @user1675122: Look at my link below :)

Answer (score 0):

The instructions are pretty clear ... and pretty simple:

1. Install your JDK on Win7 (I'd choose the 64-bit JVM for 64-bit Windows, but 32-bit will work on 64-bit Windows equally well)
2. Unpack the "eclipse" folder from the .zip file anywhere you want.  Mine happens to be in c:\eclipse.
3. Manually create a desktop and/or start menu link to eclipse/eclipse.exe
4. Here's a great reference on ["PyDev"](http://pydev.org/):

   - http://www.vogella.com/articles/Python/article.html

I'd also encourage you to install the latest/greatest Eclipse ("Juno") instead of Indigo.

Comment: Thanks! I chose Indigo because of a functional programming course on Coursera,"Scala Programming", Which at this point seems to hard for me. I then signed up for another course "Programming fundamentals with Python". I think it will be easier. It just so happens that the site that gave the instructions for installing pythondev on eclipse also had a hello world project further down that I did and ran just fine.

Comment: If Juno offers more advantages than Indigo I could put that in a separate folder and use either one, couldn't I?